# I'm having trouble with an awk script

Tags: bash, awk

I want to be able to give a country's name and have the script search a CSV file for me and pop out that country's capital. I am having issues getting the awk command to pull the capital based on my input.

```
#!/bin/bash

#searchforacountry'scapital

read -p "What country's capital are you looking for? " countryname

awk -F "\"*,\"*" -v awkvar="$countryname" '/awkvar/ {print $2}' /workspaces/Code/testfiles/countriesandcapitals.csv
```

This is my code so far. When run it gives no results after inputting a country's name.

Comment: Tip: `/awkvar/` is the culprit, the variable is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: warning] you **can't** use the syntax `/awkvar/` with a variable, you **need** to use the `~` aka `match` operator:

```
awk -F, -v country="$countryname" '$0 ~ country{print $2}' file
```

`$0` is `awk` syntax for *the entire line*, and `~` is the regex match operator. It's a lot like the `/awkvar/` part in your attempt, except that `/.../` treats its contents as a literal string rather than a variable reference.

Comment: thank you so much for your responses and for solving my issue! could you explain this section to me? $0 ~ country I do not know how it works

Comment: @JamesChin `$0` is awk syntax for "the entire line", and `~` is the regex match operator. It's a lot like the `/awkvar/` part in your attempt, except that `/.../` treats its contents as a literal string rather than a variable reference.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I add this description to my post

Comment: I guess the original intent was more like `$1 == awkvar { print $2 }`. Matching everywhere in the line is probably a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" -v awkvar="$countryname" '/awkvar/ {print $2}' /workspaces/Code/testfiles/countriesandcapitals.csv
```

will output 2nd field for each line which contain literal `awkvar`, you probably wanted to find lines containh substring which is hold in `awkvar`, which could be done using [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function (note that it does just substring check, so you do not have to care about user giving input containing character of special meaning for regular expressions) as follows

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" -v awkvar="$countryname" 'index($0,awkvar){print $2}' /workspaces/Code/testfiles/countriesandcapitals.csv
```

however note that this will also output capital name if you provide just capital name, to avoid this, if you are storing country name in 1st field you can do

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" -v awkvar="$countryname" 'index($1,awkvar){print $2}' /workspaces/Code/testfiles/countriesandcapitals.csv
```

however this would also trigger for part of names, e.g. if you give `e` as name you will get all countries having `e` anywhere in name, if you wish to limit to only triggering when whole name is given

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" -v awkvar="$countryname" '$1==awkvar{print $2}' /workspaces/Code/testfiles/countriesandcapitals.csv
```

**Disclaimer** this answer assumes you want case-sensitive solution, if this does not hold ignore this answer entirely.